# Function of aapt/AndroidManifest.xml in AAR

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-library, aar

Some of my Android libraries (AAR files) contain an `aapt/AndroidManifest.xml` as well as the root `AndroidManifest.xml`. From what I could see, these two don't differ, but the one in `aapt` seems to be optional. I couldn't find any documentation about it though.

So what's the purpose of this second manifest? And why is it added only sometimes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@NonNull
@Override
public File getAaptFriendlyManifestOutputFile() {
    return FileUtils.join(
            globalScope.getIntermediatesDir(),
            "manifests",
            "aapt",
            getVariantConfiguration().getDirName(),
            "AndroidManifest.xml");
}
```

[image]